# How to remove substring from the end of string using spark sql?

Tags: sql, database, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm using spark sql on Databricks to do data analysis, and I wand to format some fields, but it is a bit tricky.

I have two fields, `perfume` and `brand`, what I want is, to remove the `brand` name **only from the end** of the `perfume` column.

Here's an example:

[image]

I have tried this :

```sql
SELECT substring_index(perfume,brand,1),brand FROM global_temp.gv_web
```

This approach works just with some fields but in some cases it removes all the name from the perfume field like this example :

[image]

The removed fields are :

```text
Halloween Fever Halloween
Versace Pour Femme Versace
Clinique Happy Summer Spray 2009 Clinique
```

How can I fix this problem please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace` function with this regex:

```regex
(\s*BRAND\s*)*$ # removes all brand names that comes at the end
```

For cases where perfume name is the same as brand name then the output of `regexp_replace` will be empty string, using when expression you can check if it's empty then use brand name:

```sql
SELECT  CASE WHEN trim(regexp_replace(perfume, format_string('(\\s*%s\\s*)*$', brand), '')) <> ''
             THEN regexp_replace(perfume, format_string('(\\s*%s\\s*)*$', brand), '')
             ELSE brand
        END AS perfume,
        brand 
FROM global_temp.gv_web
```